# How does the aftereffect work for the Spectral Tendrils trap?

Tags: dnd-4e, traps

There's a trap defined in the Dungeon Master Guide on page 91 called Spectral Tendrils.

The **Hit** line of the trap's attack says:

> **Hit:** 2d10 + 6 necrotic damage and dazed until the end of the target's next turn.
>   *Aftereffect:* Dazed until the end of the target's next turn.

What?

Aftereffects occur after an effect that a save can end ends. There's no effect that a save can end here. Is it supposed to be "dazed (save ends)", or are they just dazed for two turns?

I checked [UpdateDMG](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive), and there's no errata for this trap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Aftereffects* happen when an effect ends, however it doesn't have to be a (save ends) effect.

From page 98 of the Rules Compendium and also page 219 of the PHB2:

> **Aftereffect:** An aftereffect automatically occurs **after another effect ends.** An “Aftereffect” entry follows the effect it applies to, which is typically in a “Hit” or an “Effect” entry.

The confusion probably comes from the fact that they follow this with a (save ends) example but it never actually says that Aftereffects *only* occur after a (save ends) effect ends.

Therefore, in the case of Spectral Tendrils, they would be dazed for two turns; once when they get hit by the trap and again when that first daze ends.

Comment: Ah, why didn't I check the RC? The PH says it's just after save effects on page 279. Thanks.